# Neo4j Cypher finding the average of node properties which have another property in common

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a "Gene" Label/node type with properties "value" and "geneName"
I have a separate Label/node type called Pathway with property "

I want to go through all the different geneName's and find the average of all the Gene's value with that Gene name. I need all those Gene's displayed as different rows. Bearing in mind I have a a lot of geneName's so I can't name them all in the query. I need to do this inside a certain Pathway.

```
MATCH (sample)-[:Measures]->(gene)-[:Part_Of]->(pathway)
WHERE pathway.pathwayName = 'Pyrimidine metabolism'
WITH sample, gene, Collect (distinct gene.geneName) AS temp
```

I have been trying to figure this out all day now and all I can manage to do is retrieve all the rows of geneNames. I'm lost from there.

```
RETURN extract(n IN temp | RETURN avg(gene.value))
```

Mabye?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should return the average gene value for each distinct gene name:

```
MATCH (sample)-[:Measures]->(gene)-[:Part_Of]->(pathway:Pathway)
WHERE pathway.pathwayName = 'Pyrimidine metabolism'
RETURN sample, gene.geneName AS name, AVG(gene.value) AS avg;
```

When you use an aggregation function (like `AVG`), it automatically uses *distinct* values for the non-aggregating values in the same `WITH` or `RETURN` clause (i.e., `sample` and `gene.geneName` in the above query).

For efficiency, I have also added the label to the `pathway` nodes so that neo4j can start off by scanning just Pathway nodes instead of all nodes. In addition, you should consider [creating an index](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-schema-index.html#schema-index-create-an-index) on `:Pathway(pathwayName)`, so that the search for the Pathway is as fast as possible.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and answer! However while I run the code, it's given me this error:                                                                    AVG(gene.value) can only handle numerical values, or null. And the gene.values are all numerical (decimals to be precise).

Comment: Perhaps they are actually numeric strings? For efficiency, you should store them ,as numbers instead of strings. But, if you cannot change the stored values, you can use `AVG(TOFLOAT(genie.value))`.